# Update JMenu and JMenu font after JMenuBar is visible

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jmenu

The following code below creates a simple GUI with a button in the centre which, when clicked, should update the font of the `JMenuBar` components. To do this a method `setMyFont` fires in an `ActionListener` on the `JButton`. However after several listed attempts I have failed to accomplish this but I am unaware of why. The code used in `setMyFont` is below

```
public void setMyFont(Font f, Font f2) {
    //Attempt 1 in the hope it would autodetect that font
    //had changed and just update
    menuFont = f;
    menuItemFont = f2;

    //Attempt 2 in the hope on the repaint it would update 
    //the font with the new UIManager properties
    UIManager.put("Menu.font", menuFont);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", menuItemFont);

    //Attempt 3 in the hope that going over each component 
    //individually would update the font
    for(Component comp: getComponents()) {
        if(comp instanceof JMenu) {
            comp.setFont(menuFont);
        } else {
            comp.setFont(menuItemFont);
        }
    }

    validate();
    repaint();
}
```

Is there a reason that the font doesn't update on the components with the current code? Also how could I change my code to allow for the font to update on the components even though they are already created?

---

**Full Code for SSCCE**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3206847208968227199L;
    JButton but;
    MenuBar mB;

    private Main() {
        setSize(600, 600);

        mB = new MenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());

        but = new JButton("Change Font");
        but.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
        add(but);

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2055260049565317972L;
        Font menuFont = new Font("Courier", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 12);
        Font menuItemFont = new Font("sans-serif", 0, 12);
        JMenu menu, subMenu;

        MenuBar() {
            UIManager.put("Menu.font", menuFont);
            UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", menuItemFont);

            menu = new JMenu("Menu");

            subMenu = new JMenu("Sub Menu");
            subMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            subMenu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            menu.add(subMenu);

            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));

            add(menu);

            menu = new JMenu("Another Menu");
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            add(menu);
        }

        public void setMyFont(Font f, Font f2) {
            //Attempt 1 in the hope it would autodetect that font
            //had changed and just update
            menuFont = f;
            menuItemFont = f2;

            //Attempt 2 in the hope on the repaint it would update 
            //the font with the new UIManager properties
            UIManager.put("Menu.font", menuFont);
            UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", menuItemFont);

            //Attempt 3 in the hope that going over each component 
            //individually would update the font
            for(Component comp: getComponents()) {
                if(comp instanceof JMenu) {
                    comp.setFont(menuFont);
                } else {
                    comp.setFont(menuItemFont);
                }
            }

            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mB.setMyFont(new Font("sans-serif", 0, 12), new Font("Courier", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 12));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. After setting the font, you need to have each component in the hierarchy call update it's UI - [SwingUtilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#updateComponentTreeUI(java.awt.Component)) has a convenience method for this

   ```
   UIManager.put("Menu.font",  menuFont);
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( Main.this );
   ```
2. Use the [FontUIResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/FontUIResource.html) class eg

   ```
   FontUIResource menuFont = new FontUIResource("Courier", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 12);
   ```

The following code adapted from the posted SSCCE works for me:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3206847208968227199L;
    JButton but;
    MenuBar mB;

    private Main() {
        setSize(600, 600);

        mB = new MenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(mB);

        but = new JButton("Change Font");
        but.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
        add(but);

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2055260049565317972L;
        Font menuFont = new FontUIResource("Courier", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 12);
        Font menuItemFont = new FontUIResource("sans-serif", 0, 12);
        JMenu menu, subMenu;

        MenuBar() {
            UIManager.put("Menu.font", menuFont);
            UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", menuItemFont);

            menu = new JMenu("Menu");

            subMenu = new JMenu("Sub Menu");
            subMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            subMenu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            menu.add(subMenu);

            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));

            add(menu);

            menu = new JMenu("Another Menu");
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            menu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub Item"));
            menu.add(new JMenu("Sub Menu"));
            add(menu);
        }

        public void setMyFont(Font f, Font f2) {

            menuFont = f;
            menuItemFont = f2;
            UIManager.put("Menu.font", menuFont);
            UIManager.put("MenuItem.font", menuItemFont);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Main.this);
        }
    }

    private class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mB.setMyFont(new FontUIResource("sans-serif", 0, 12), new FontUIResource("Courier", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 12));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) Using the updateComponentTree(...) is easier than writing your own recursive method to get all components added to the menu bar. Although you should only need to invoke the method on the menu bar, not the frame.

Comment: @camickr RE invoke on the menu bar, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic), `invoke the SwingUtilities updateComponentTreeUI method once per `[top level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: @copeg Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am probably doing it wrong, calling `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( Main.this );` after setting the fonts does not do anything. Should I be putting outside the `setMyFont` function or should it work. *I also implemented `FontUIResource`, it didn't make a difference*

Comment: @copeg, In general when you play with the properties of the UIManager you would probably want to do it at the frame level since you want it to affect all components on the frame. In this case since we are only affecting components added to the menubar you only need to update the tree of the menubar. The `updateCompnentTreeeUI(...)` method takes a component as a parameter. It just does a recursive search from that component.

Comment: @Dan, `after setting the fonts does not do anything.` - the `updateComponentTreeUI(...)` method will only update properties of a component that were created with a `UIResource` interface. The problem with your posted code is that you have already replaced the default Fonts in the UIManager before you created all your Swing components. So get rid of all that logic. You should only be updating the UIManager properties in the ActionListener

Comment: @camickr Thanks for all the help

Comment: @copeg Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 3):

```
    mB = new MenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
```

Your ActionListener is not working on the menubar that you added to the frame.

The code should be:

```
    mB = new MenuBar();
    //setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
    setJMenuBar(mB);
```

The getComponents() method is not recursive. So your loop will only get the JMenu compnents added to the JMenuBar, not the JMenuItems.

Also when creating your fonts why not use a larger font size so you can actually see if something changes.

Also in your posted code, setting the UIManager Font properties before you create the components defeats the purpose of having the button. Your menus will already be the desired font.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
    public class MenuFontChange {

    public static void changeMenuFont(JMenuBar jBar, Font font) {
        Component[] components = jBar.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.setFont(font);
            changeMenuItemFont((JMenu) component, font);
        }
    }

    public static void changeMenuItemFont(JMenu jMenu, Font font) {
        int n = jMenu.getItemCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            JMenuItem item = jMenu.getItem(i);
            item.setFont(font);
        }
    }
```